# Word doc looks different in 365 and 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, office365

I am using Office 365 for the first time.

I have a beautiful word document carefully layed out on my Mac and stored in One-drive.

when I open it in Word 2013 at the Office (on a windows PC) It looks totally different - there are large empty spaces, text no longer fits in the text boxes, and blank pages are interspersed.

I verified the margins and the styles and they ARE the same as I would expect.

anyone know whats going on?

Comment: This is because Office 365 is Office 2016 not Office 2013.  As for why the document looks different you have a setting different.

Comment: What settings could I have different that aren't part of the document?  As I said, I confirmed styles and margins

Comment: Have you confirmed the fonts used on the mac are present on Windows?  Can you post screenshots showing the differences?

Comment: Ah I believe that is the issue.  I used Palatino and Helvitica Nuvue and I don't see them on the PC.   Thanks